# Git: Who has modified this line?

Tags: git

If I found a bug in my application, sometimes I need to know which commits have affected to the bug source code line. I'm wondering which is the best approach to do it with Git.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

To see commits affecting line 40 of file foo:

```
git blame -L 40,+1 foo
```

The +1 means exactly one line. To see changes for lines 40-60, it's:

```
git blame -L 40,+21 foo
```

OR

```
git blame -L 40,60 foo
```

The second number can be an offset designated with a '+', or a line number. [git blame docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame)

Comment: How can I get the entire line history, not only the last one?

Comment: @Pedro you probably want `git log -L`. See this answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19757493/2356383

Answer (score 43):

I'd use the [`git blame`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame) command. That's pretty much exactly what it is for. The documentation should get you started.

Comment: will this give me the entire line history or only the last one?
What if the line has be modified more than once and i want to check the changes each time the line has been modified.

Comment: @YashKalwani It only shows the last change. You probably want [`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) instead`.

Answer (score 9):

```
git blame filename
```

is the best command to show you this info

Answer (score 9):

If you only need the last change:

```
git blame
```

Otherwise, you could try to automatically find the offending change with

```
git bisect
```

Comment: +1 for bisect. Good for trying to figure out which commit broke something without knowning exactly what is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
git annotate filename (or)

git blame filename
```