# Git, With given change in source, how to find commit number?

Tags: git, commit

I Know in file foo.cpp Following Line has been added some time this year

```
if(engL.showPrompt()>engL.lessPrompt())
     executeScript();
```

How to find which commit pushed this change?

Comment: possible duplicate of [git, commit log for specific \_line\_ in file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435343/git-commit-log-for-specific-line-in-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the change is not in the last commit, you can use

```
git log -S"if(engL.showPrompt()>engL.lessPrompt()) executeScript()" -- path/to/file
```

Comment: aha this looks more promising , let me try it

Comment: I get this fatal: bad revision 'if(engL.showPrompt()>engL.lessPrompt())'

Comment: Did you include the `-S` (capital S) flag? Also, if you want to use a regular expression, replace it with `-G`.

Comment: aha, it was space between S and "if..." creating problem. without space it is working great, Thank you alot.

Answer (score 4):

`git blame foo.cpp` will show you line by line what commit was the last one to contribute to that line.

Comment: with git blame the problem is it talks about from begining which is three year old in my case. and you need to go through every line of code to find. So I was thinking if there is way if I simply pass one line of text like executeScript(); and it gives me the commit number

Comment: @EfanHarris See `-L` of `git blame`. It allows you to specify a line range or a regex to search for.