# How to maintain Git's change history of file content which is extracted to another file?

Tags: git, version-control

Currently I have 1 file at changeset 1:

A.java

```
statements_0
statements_1
statements_2
```

During refactoring, I move statements_1 into B.java. So that:

A.java:

```
statements_0
statements_2
```

B.java

```
statements_1
```

Is there a way to maintain the change history of statements_1 ?

Meaning that, in future commits, I can always trace back (and do diff) on statements_1 up to changeset 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a

```
git log --follow -L1,1:B.java
```

(The `-L` option of [`git log`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) is from [git1.8.4](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v1.8.4/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.4.txt#L210) and is [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19757493/6309))

You can also use [`git blame`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame), as [suggested in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18314801/6309), except you would need to add the `-C10` option to detect moves between files.

('`10`' because the default bound for number of alphanumeric characters that Git must detect as moving/copying between files for it to associate those lines with the parent commit is 40. And if '`statements_1`' is actually '`statements_1`', it would be too small to be detected).

```
git rblame -M -n -L1,1 -C B.java
```