# List all commits that change specific lines in a specific commit

Tags: git, git-commit, git-log

Suppose a commit X changes line 500 of the file foo.java. I want to see all the past commits that have changed this line.

Inspired by [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435343/retrieve-the-commit-log-for-a-specific-line-in-a-file), I understand that since git 1.8.4, we can use the `-L` option of `git log` to view the evolution of a specific line range. So I use `git log -L 500,500:foo.java`

However, I got a error saying

> file foo.java has only 450 lines

I suspect that the reason is that my `git log` command operates on the HEAD. But between commit X and HEAD, the file foo.java has been modified and ended up with only 450 lines.

So, how can I get all the commits that have changed this line 500 from commit X?

Answer (score 0):

You could try that same command for each SHA1, with [`git rev-list`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list)

windows (with Gnu On Windows for the xargs command)

```
git rev-list HEAD|xargs git log -1 -L 500,500:foo.java 2>NUL
```

Unix:

```
git rev-list HEAD|xargs git log -1 -L 500,500:foo.java 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: May you explain a bit more about the command? Where should I put the commit SHA1? What is `HEAD|xargs` and `2>/dev/null`? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @lda that is basic scripting, using redirection unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70963/difference-between-2-2-dev-null-dev-null-and-dev-null-21, and pipe |. You don't have to put a SHA1: git rev-list is supposed to list *all* SHA1 for you in your repo.

Comment: @lda But if you have to put a SHA1 '`X`', you can use `git rev-list X..HEAD`: Replace '`X`' by your SHA1.

Comment: thanks, but I got an error using your command (without the 2>NUL part): `fatal: More than one commit to dig from: a7d7f9e4036bff9ab524b88cb8210c97ef36bc9c and 24767679c82f94eab5d81346bdbdf63f8bdbca36?`

Comment: @lda are you on Windows? are you using a simple cmd session or git-bash?

Comment: @lda then why are you using the Windows syntax?

Comment: Sorry, I meant I used your command without the last part. The command is `git rev-list HEAD|xargs git log -1 -L 500,500:foo.java`