# How to find which commit added a line of code..?

Tags: git, github

I'm really not even sure how to start with this, but it seems like the sort of thing that should be available.

In a project we have a particular line of code:

```
if(!current_user_can('administrator'))
```

I'm trying to figure out how added that line and what issue/commit it belonged to, but I can't seem to figure out a way to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve the commit log for a specific line in a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435343/retrieve-the-commit-log-for-a-specific-line-in-a-file)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `git blame <file>` and navigate to the relevant line of code. Alongside the line itself it will display the commit hash that introduced it and the author of that patch.