# Git log for only part of a file?

Tags: git, version-control, git-log, git-history-graph

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5493663/1172541 explains how you can do a git log command for a file. Is there a way to track how *part* of a file changed with git log or other git command? (Of course, this would definitely strains git's diff engines, as the length and line numbers of the part changes. git is pretty good at that thing though.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve the commit log for a specific line in a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435343/retrieve-the-commit-log-for-a-specific-line-in-a-file)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Yup](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log).

```
git log -L<start>,<end>:<file>
```

For example,

```
git log -L55,65:app.js
```

will show a log for lines 55-65 in `app.js`.

To view a single line, use the same value for both start and end

```
git log -L55,55:app.js
```

Also works with `gitk`

```
gitk -L55,65:app.js
```