# How can i check which line is change by whom in git?

Tags: git

I want to check who added the few lines of code in the particular file , as all 3 developers are working on the same file .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve the commit log for a specific line in a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435343/retrieve-the-commit-log-for-a-specific-line-in-a-file)

Comment: `git log`'s options `-S` and `-L` can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this via `git blame filename`.

Comment: Beware, this will show the last person to edit a line, and not necessarily who added it, which would be in the commit history.

Answer (score 1):

To see who was the last person to touch each line of code, use `git blame`. To see which commits inserted or removed certain pattern/lines that you're interested in, use [the pickaxe](http://www.philandstuff.com/2014/02/09/git-pickaxe.html). It helps you find which commits made changes that match a pattern you're interested in (e.g. "who changed this line use a debug rather that critical logger" even if the line currently is critical).

Answer (score 1):

You can use git blame with the -L  option, where n is the first line and m the last line inspected. The following example will show the last commit done to line number 10.

```
git blame -L 10,10
```

If you want the complete history including the first commit (you ask for when the line was added), you can use git log, e.g:

```
git log -L 10,10:myFile.txt
```