# Git log diffs around known line

Tags: git, git-log, git-blame

Is it possible to log commits of file in git, when I know certain line, and want to show commits which edited the lines above or below that line in the scale of N lines?

I want to find, which commit broke the functionality, when certain method call or piece of code should be somewhere around another method call, but it is not, and I don't know the exact name of the missing method call or piece of code.

Comment: Are you looking for `git blame` ?

Comment: Maybe this question is similar to this one: [Retrieve the commit log for a specific line in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435343/retrieve-the-commit-log-for-a-specific-line-in-a-file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve the commit log for a specific line in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435343/retrieve-the-commit-log-for-a-specific-line-in-a-file)

Comment: Possible duplicate, what is wrong with you people? I clearly stated I'm interested lines around, using the known line as an anchor. I want to find, which commit broke the functionality, when certain method call should be *somewhere* around another method call, but it is not.

Answer (score 0):

using `git blame` would seem like the way to go: 
`git blame -L <from_line>,<to_line> <file>`

 something like: 
`git blame -L 20,30 main.cpp`

if you need to see who made a commit affecting those lines before a certain revision , you can do so by passing it to the git blame command:

`git blame -L 20,30 <rev> main.cpp`

for more options just run
`git blame --h` or `git blame --help` for more extensive help