# View git history of specific line

Tags: git

I want to view the commit history related to the specific line in the file. I know we can get the history of the file. Are there any commands available to sort only the commits related to one specific line?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieve the commit log for a specific line in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435343/retrieve-the-commit-log-for-a-specific-line-in-a-file)

Answer (score 180, accepted):

bomz gave the right option but with wrong syntax. Fixed line would look like this:

```
git log -L '/the line from your file/,+1:path/to/your/file.txt'
```

The meaning of argument to `-L` is "find the first occurrence of regex `/the line from your file/`, in `path/to/your/file.txt` and show the log regarding one line range starting at this point (meaning, just this line, but you could say +5 instead)".

The caveat is, if the line contains characters with special meaning in regex, you need to escape them.

However, **it's likely much simpler to use line number**, like this:

```
git log -L15,+1:'path/to/your/file.txt'
```

(for line 15 of file `path/to/your/file.txt`)

In both cases `+1` can be replaced with bigger number to get more line, or with regex to match the end of selected range.

Detailed description from [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

> ```
> -L <start>,<end>:<file>
> -L :<funcname>:<file>
> ```
>
> Trace the evolution of the line range given by "<start>,<end>" (or the function name regex <funcname>) within the
>   <file>. You may not give any pathspec limiters. This is currently
>   limited to a walk starting from a single revision, i.e., you may only
>   give zero or one positive revision arguments. You can specify this
>   option more than once.
>
> <start> and <end> can take one of these forms:
>
> - number
>
>   If <start> or <end> is a number, it specifies an absolute line number
>     (lines count from 1).
> - /regex/
>
>   This form will use the first line matching the given POSIX regex. If
>     <start> is a regex, it will search from the end of the previous -L
>     range, if any, otherwise from the start of file. If <start> is
>     “^/regex/”, it will search from the start of file. If <end> is a
>     regex, it will search starting at the line given by <start>.
> - +offset or -offset
>
>   This is only valid for <end> and will specify a number of lines before
>     or after the line given by <start>.
>
> If “:<funcname>” is given in place of <start> and <end>, it is a
>   regular expression that denotes the range from the first funcname line
>   that matches <funcname>, up to the next funcname line. “:<funcname>”
>   searches from the end of the previous -L range, if any, otherwise from
>   the start of file. “^:<funcname>” searches from the start of file.

Comment: There is a missing quota after -L :
`git log -L'15,+1:path/to/your/file.txt'`

Using no quote at all seems to work :
`git log -L 15,+1:path/to/your/file.txt `

Comment: @JohannBzh Good catch, fixed. Quotes are optional in most cases, but they are necessary for paths with spaces or other characters requiring escaping - so it's a bit safer to just quote all paths by default.

Comment: There has to be a space after -L

Comment: @Hemanth That's how the man page shows it, but it actually works both ways. That is the customary for the one letter options to accept the rest of the token as the input, if there is any. I mean, at least it works for me, if it actually doesn't work in some environment, I'd be happy to correct.

Comment: @Frax It doesn't work without the quote on windows git version 2.42.0.windows.2. git log -L68,+10:'Services/MyService.cs' gives Missing argument in parameter list but git log -L'68,+10:Services/MyService.cs' works

Answer (score 11):

You could use git log https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log

```
git log -L'the line from your file' -- path/to/your/file.txt
```

Comment: Example that works for me: `git log -L 465,469:src/file.c`

Answer (score 10):

The other answers here cover the question as asked very well, but sometimes you want to see this history for another branch without first checking out that branch.

```
git log branch-name -L '/regex/',+1:path/to/your/file.txt
```

works very well for these cases. Or you already know the line number:

```
git log branch-name -'L15,+1':'path/to/your/file.txt'
```