# How to get all the changes on a specific line of a specific file contained in a git repository?

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, gitpython

We have a git repository we have been using for many years. Say, it is a Java - maven project. The project has `pom.xml` file that contains important information like

```
<model_location>path/to/file/model_version</model_location>
```

I would like to get all model version names from the git repository. Hopefully, I can use GitPython library to do it. I wrote the following code.

```
repo = Repo('/path/to/repository')
remote_origin = repo.remotes.origin
remote_origin.pull()
path = "path/to/pom.xml"

commits = repo.iter_commits('--all', max_count=1000, paths=path)
for commit in commits:
    committer_name = commit.committer.name
    timestamp = time.strftime("%F %T", time.localtime(commit.committed_date))
    hexsha = commit.hexsha
    print(f"{hexsha}\t{committer_name}\t{timestamp}")
```

The code shows the following result.

```
afdb36153a53bc45eff52c319a9541498e1c3ce1    committer-1 2020-01-30 09:57:01
e85ca97121384fb34b0fdc1fa04cf78b6c1cd109    committer-1 2020-01-28 13:45:29
61bbf5d706b9dd2caa7b75e0374946ec1b96994c    committer-2 2020-01-23 17:44:20
...
c10ead963802053147488b93626ca0b9aab643b1    committer-3 2015-01-06 09:04:33
cf74128281e9374cca8e88a0e23e52f55e37f109    committer-3 2014-12-05 15:01:24
```

I got a list of commit ids but I have no idea how can I read the `model_location` tag in `pom.xml` of a specific commit id.

The purpose of this is to know which model was used at a specific period. For example, `model version 3.14` had been used between 2014-12-05 15:01:24 and 2015-01-06 09:04:33 and `committer-3` checked in the model etc.

I would be really grateful if you could let me know it. I wrote another script that does the same with svn but I am not familiar with git.

Thanks,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435343/retrieve-the-commit-log-for-a-specific-line-in-a-file

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my hasty question. I found a solution.

```
        res = repo.git.show(f"{hexsha}:{path}/{os.path.basename(pom_xml_path)}")
        for line in res.split("\n"):
            match = re.match(regex, line)
            if match:
                model_location = match.group(1)
                model_name = os.path.basename(model_location)
                print(f"{hexsha}\t{committer_name}\t{model_name}\t{timestamp}")
```