# Is there a way to see commit hash instead of HEAD?

Tags: git, git-merge-conflict

I got conflict:
[image]

Is there an option to show last commit hash for changes at `HEAD` (green underline).

I expect this: `HEAD, 476ce2c Simplify interface: remove 'rs' parameter`
which will be similar to `>>>>>>>` section

Answer (score 4):

You could in-place replace it yourself

```sh
find ./ \( -type d -name .git -prune \) -o -type f -print0 | xargs \
    sed -i "s/<<<<<<<< HEAD/<<<<<<<< $(git rev-parse --short HEAD)/"
```

---

Consider `git log --pretty=reference -n 1 head` as the command (`git rev-parse --short` is just the short hash) or refer to the docs to build exactly what you want as `git log --pretty=format:"whatever you like" -n 1 head` https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats

`find|xargs` modified from top answer to [How to do a recursive find/replace of a string with awk or sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1583282/4541045)

Comment: Also note that while this should work for the general case, I'm not absolutely certain it behaves as-expected during a merge, and I'm hoping for a better answer!

Comment: For some reason, when rebasing on multiple commit, the `<<<<<<<< HEAD <<<<<<<<` does not points to the same as `HEAD`...

Comment: @Lærne what does happen? and what do you mean by _"rebasing on multiple commit"_? it sounds like you might have a different Question than the one posted here, which you could ask!

Comment: From what I could try, if `a` is on top of `b` which is on top of `c` and `x` is on top of `c`, and you rebase `x` on `a` and you have conflict between `b` and `x`, for some reason `HEAD` points to `a`, not `b`. This answer will replace `HEAD` with `a` and not `b`, which is the commit that failed (and was pointed by `HEAD` at the time of the failure?), so I take it as wrong in the general sense of the question asked.

Comment: hmm.. to me, this reads as if you have some `c+b+a` and then `c+x`, then you want to rebase to `c+b+a+a'+x`, where `a'` is a patch to fix the conflict .. my understanding is that `a` is really the `HEAD` in such a situation, even though the conflict may originate in `b` (while if you instead tried to rebase on it `c+b+b'+x`, the `b` would be the `HEAD`) .. it only means the tip (top?) of the branch, not necessarily the precise origin of the issue .. if you wanted to really find not the `HEAD`, but a precise commit a conflict issue comes from, you could combine `git blame` and `git log`, but ..

Comment: you may find more than one commit is involved in the conflict, and would need to decide if you wish to only take the latest (beware: it may not be first in the block!) or would you move to inject additional artificial conflict lines? (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435343/retrieve-the-commit-log-for-a-specific-line-in-a-file ) .. finally, in such a situation, you may find it's better to `git cherry-pick` your `x` into a new branch based on `a`

Comment: I have a` c+b+a` and a `c+x` and I want a `c+b+a+x`. Let's say that `a` modifies `a.txt`, `b` modifies `b.txt` and `c` modifies `c.txt`. If `x` modifies `b.txt`, and we run `git rebase a x`, then `HEAD` will point to `a` even though the _only_ commit involved in the conflict are `b` and `x`. `a` may be the actual head because we want to conflict resolution on top of `a`, it remains that I don't know what the code between `<<<<<<< HEAD` and `=======` was meant to do, and I'm not told which commit created that code so I could check myself what was the intention.