# TFVC How to get Author(Annotate) with line number?

Tags: command-line, azure-devops, tfvc

Actually what I want is like this on [Git command answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19757493/15777421).

But I need to this TFVC Command.

I have project on TFS Local Server, and I'm using Java Process Builder and I need to command for get last committer information with specific line number on TFVC.

I looked at this site but could not find enough information.

Comment: Looks like you're looking for `tfpt annotate /noprompt` to get the changeset number for each line, you can then use `tf vs changeset` to get the changeset details. You'll need to install Team Explorer 2015 or a full version of Visual Studio 2015. 
https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202015&wt.mc_id=o~msft~vscom~older-downloads
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer2015Power

Comment: Thank you for answer, I was installed Visual Studio 2019 Community Version. And using tf.exe on command line. I'm didnt see on this site annotate command : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands?view=azure-devops. I tried installed Power Tools but it didn't work. Will the annotate command come after installing power tools?

Comment: And, I need him who made the last change to which line. "changeset" shows the changes in the whole class.

Comment: The powertools only work when Visual Studio 2015 is installed, like I said, only then is `tfpt` installed. You can use `tfpt annotate` to get the changeset number that last changed a line, then use `tf vc changeset` to find the author of that changeset.

Comment: you'll need to uninstall/reinstall the power tools after installing Visual Studio 2015.